# How can I redirect the "bin" and "obj" directories to a different location?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to use a different location for the `bin` and `obj` directories?

For example, if my project is in **C:\my\myprojects.csproj**, how can I have the `obj` and `bin` directories in, say, **D:\otherdirectory\bin** and **D:\otherdirectory\obj**. The Visual Studio project option offer only to redirect the `bin` directory, not the `obj` directory.

Also, bonus question: Can I use environment variables, not full or relative paths?

Is this possible?

Comment: This could be the canonical question for (completely) separating source files from generated files in Visual Studio projects (unless there is an older/better one). Answers would need to be added and/or updated for the later versions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Refer to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx) and use the nodes **BaseOutputPath** (for the `bin` folder) and **BaseIntermediateOutputPath** (for the `obj` folder) in the .proj file.

Given below is a way to modify your debug and release folders relative to `bin` -

In Solution Explorer, select the C# project you want to configure
build parameters on.

Next, from the Visual Studio menu bar, select *Project* → *Properties*. The Property Pages dialog will appear for your project.

Choose the Configuration (*Release*/*Debug*) you want to change and expand the Configuration Properties node in the left hand pane. Select the Studio is placed in the "Output path" attribute of the *Outputs*
property sheet.

Be aware that the output path is specified separately for each kind of
build configuration, and that setting it on one configuration doesn't
set it on all the remaining ones.

Original source - http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32040244/how-to-change-the-obj-folder.aspx

Comment: Is it correct you can't change the obj directory from the UI?

Comment: @user380719 - Yes, as far as I know, you cannot change directory of bin and obj folders from UI.

Comment: Hum. In VS2015, setting the **IntermediateOutputPath** (no Base) works fine. But I can't get it to work with **BaseIntermediateOutputPath**. I can't get **BaseOutputPath** to work either. Any idea why?

Comment: Also, @SachinShanbhag your eggheadcafe link is now deader than dead. Even archive.org doesn't have a copy. :-(

Comment: The link at the end is broken (*"The page you requested was removed."*).

Comment: **BaseOutputPath** key doesn't work in VS2019 but **IntermediateOutputPath** works fine. The Debug and Release output path can be set in Project->Properties->Build screen or by editing the .csproj file, we have to provide the full path.

**IntermediateOutputPath** does not work fully either, VS will still creates a obj/ folder and drops a few small files there

Comment: To get **BaseOutputPath** to work you have to blank out or delete any **OutputPath** you see further down the .csproj file.

Answer (score 17):

To move `obj` directories out of your code base to another common folder you can do the following. Create `Directory.Build.props` in the root directory of your solution with the following content:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(SolutionDir)\_Obj\$(MSBuildProjectName)\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

To keep folder structure in your common `obj` directory the same as in your solution you can create files with the same and similar content in every subfolder of your solution. E.g. If you have subfolder `Algorithms` which contains several projects you can put file with the following content into it:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(SolutionDir)\_Obj\Algorithms\$(MSBuildProjectName)\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Use `BaseOutputPath` for `bin` folder.

- More info on [Directory.Build.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019)
- More info on [MSBuild macroses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=vs-2019)

Comment: remove all old bin and obj dirs before using this setting overwise you will get compiler erros

Answer (score 0):

In the Project-options in the tab Build you can choose the output path (in the bottom-section).

Comment: thats the bin folder, not the obj folder

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2013, this is specified in project "Configuration Properties/General/Intermediate Directory".
[image]

Comment: This thread is one of several that came up when I was searching the answer for MSVC 2013 and I wasted too much time unsuccessfully trying to get BaseIntermediateOutputPath to work when I discovered this setting which solved my problem and diverted OBJs to a RAM drive folder..