# Visual Studio creates a new obj folder in the existing obj folder

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

So as my question states, Visual Studio is creating new obj folders in my existing obj folder every time I build my solution. This then causes an issue where I have multiple Assembly attributes. The only solution I have found so far is to manually delete the original obj folder before every build, for every project in the solution. However, this is time consuming because there are several projects in the solution and I can't write a batch script for it because the folder structure for the projects is not consistent.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can fix this?

[image]

Edit: None of my coworkers are having the same issue and we have all pulled the project from the same Perforce server.

Comment: I feel for you, hate it when stuff like this happens. Its a long shot but checkout this answer and then check your proj file and see if anything untoward has happened to the BaseIntermediateOutputPath maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4735571/1370442